# Altering table after generating CRUD code gives error in yii

Tags: yii, attributes

I have a table with 2 fields and generated CRUD which is working well. I added to 2 more fields to that table and applied required changes in model, controller and view. But yii shows error for the newly added fields saying that those attributes are not defined.

This is my model code:

```
class Product extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('title, subTitle, image, shortDesc, longDesc, seo_title, focus_keywords, meta_desc, meta_url, created, updated', 'required'),
            array('status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('title, subTitle, image', 'length', 'max'=>128),
            array('seo_title, focus_keywords, meta_desc, meta_url', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, title, subTitle, image, shortDesc, longDesc, status, seo_title, focus_keywords, meta_desc, meta_url, created, updated', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'subTitle' => 'Sub Title',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'shortDesc' => 'Short Desc',
            'longDesc' => 'Long Desc',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'seo_title' => 'Seo Title',
            'focus_keywords' => 'Focus Keywords',
            'meta_desc' => 'Meta Desc',
            'meta_url' => 'Meta Url',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'updated' => 'Updated',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
        $criteria->compare('subTitle',$this->subTitle,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('shortDesc',$this->shortDesc,true);
        $criteria->compare('longDesc',$this->longDesc,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('seo_title',$this->seo_title,true);
        $criteria->compare('focus_keywords',$this->focus_keywords,true);
        $criteria->compare('meta_desc',$this->meta_desc,true);
        $criteria->compare('meta_url',$this->meta_url,true);
        $criteria->compare('created',$this->created,true);
        $criteria->compare('updated',$this->updated,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Product the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

Comment: submit your model code. or simply you have not written more code then regenerate model.

Comment: Wich are the new fields? And what is the _exact_ error Yii is giving?

Comment: seo_title, focus_keywords, meta_desc and meta_url are the new fields. and when i try opening create form it gives seo_title attribute is not defined and if i comment seo_title field in form it gives same error for the nxt attribute i.e focus_keywords and likewise for all new attributes.

Comment: clear runtime/cache folder

Comment: At least try and tell how the error is generated. Which action? method? line number? ... Nothing!

Comment: The error got solved by clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear Yii cache (protected/runtime)